# Reallocate a std::vector of struct

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, struct

Let's say we have a `std::vector` of `struct`s:

```
struct abc {
    wstring a;     // length between 0 and 200, 100 on average
    long b;
    long c;
};

std::vector<abc> v;    // 1 - 10 millions of items will be there
```

What happens in case of a reallocation (for example because capacity is too small when `push_back()`, or if I suddenly increase the capacity myself with `v.reserve(v.size() + 100000`)?

More precsily:

1. will **all the data be potentially rewritten** (i.e. all the `wstrings` are all rewritten, etc.)

or

2. a vector of struct kind-of internally "keeps record of pointers" to each individual struct, so if the vector is rewritten, **only these pointers are rewritten, but not the actual data**

?

---

To make the question clearer, does it look like this

[image]

or like this:

[image]

or this one:

[image]

or another way?

---

Additional informations for future reference:

```
struct abc { wstring a; int b; int c; }; 
wcout << sizeof(wstring);   // 32
wcout << sizeof(int);       // 4
wcout << sizeof(abc);       // 40, so this means there's probably no extra byte 
                            //     used by the "struct" envelope itself
wcout << sizeof(tuple<wstring, int, int>); // 40 too
```

Comment: As long as the element type is no-throw movable, a vector reallocation will move each element. You won't copy and of the string data.

Comment: It's odd to ask an "A or B" question where B has a whole different premise than A.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think the OP is mistaken about the underlying structure of a `std::vector<abc>`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux maybe I expressed badly the 2. I edited it.

Comment: vector contains the actual data, not pointers to them. So all data will be **moved** to another location (so, the string itself won't be copied, just the pointer inside)

Comment: Yes exactly @Xirema , that's precisely the question I'm asking : does reallocating a `std::vector<abc>` rewrites only the address of each struct or the actual data inside the struct ?

Comment: @Basj Not better, maybe worse. The problem I'm trying to highlight you seem to be asking "If I have to increase capacity, what will happen? Does it rewrite everything or not?" but you completely change the question in the middle of the 2nd option.

Comment: The move assumes you are using a modern compiler.

Comment: The strings are typically optimized for short values. So the short strings will be copied and the long ones will have their pointers copied.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux My question is more or less: how is stored byte per byte the content of a `std::vector<abc>`? I'm trying to understand a bit visually [like this](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS60/PresentationArrays/int_array_10.JPG).

Comment: `std::string` uses a pointer to the string unless it uses a small string optimization. This will get moved (instead of copied) if you use a modern compiler (c++11)

Comment: It's actually neither diagram.

Comment: The wstring is typically a structure that has a pointer to the string data. This structure itself would be in your A diagram. I said typically because a small string optimization may have small fixed size strings in the actual structure like your A diagram.

Comment: @drescherjm Is the 3rd diagram I added more or less correct ?

Comment: No the whole wstring structure is in the abc structure. However the wstring structure typically has a pointer to the string.

Comment: With my comments said. I don't think the standard library forces an implementation of wstring. Other library writers may choose a different internal structure of wstring. One such difference is a small string optimization.

Comment: You can investigate your implementation a little with the sizeof() operator on different wstrings and the sizeof() your abc struct. Remember there may be padding in the structs so the sum of the sizes of the members of abc may not be the same as you get for the abc struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector` stores `abc` objects, not pointers to them. Prior to C++11 expanding the capacity of the vector beyond what has been allocated (which may be greater than vector's size) would require copying the actual objects into the newly allocated array.

Starting with C++11 [`MoveInsertable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveInsertable) concept has been introduced. Now the data is moved from the old location to the new location, which may be significantly cheaper in terms of both reallocations and CPU cycles. In particular, the `wstring`s inside `abc`s would not require copying the content of the string itself, which may be a rather big potential saving.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the question with images to make it  clearer. Would it be somewhere in the middle of my 2 images? (If you could add an image, it would be a wonderful answer, but I know it takes time to do it!)

Comment: @Basj It is the last one, assuming that the strings are long, or that there's no short string optimization. With move semantics of C++11 the content of your strings does not get copied, only pointers.

Comment: How to enable to `MoveInsertable` mechanism when creating such a vector of struct? Is it automatically happening, or should I do something in the code?

Comment: It's automatic.

Comment: @Basj If you are using C++11, it happens automatically, unless you "fight" it - for example, by deleting the move constructor.

Comment: Note that the the move-constructor and move-assignment operator should be `noexcept`  ; otherwise vector has to copy instead of move in order to meet exception guarantees  (i.e. you can't risk move some objects and then have the next move throw -- there's no "unmove" to undo that operation)

Comment: @M.M what should I do in the code with noexcept ? can you give an example ?

Comment: ***what should I do in the code with noexcept*** In your current code with struct `abc` nothing. You are good. This is the point above about it happening automatically unless you fight it.